# Better way for memory sanitization in C++ to void data leakage?

Tags: c++, memory-management, memory-leaks, sanitization, delete-operator

While working in "C", i was using sanitization techniques to avoid data leakages, as guided by CERT also like :

`memset(mem_name, '\0', mem_size);
 free(mem_name);`

1. Does `delete()`, do it automatically, in **C++** ?
2. If not, what is better way to do it in **C++**, using `delete()` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Does delete(), do it automatically, in C++ ?

No

2. If not, what is better way to do it in C++, using delete() ?

In general this would be wrong in C++:

```
Foo* p = new Foo();
memset(p, 0, sizeof(Foo));
delete p;
```

The problem is that `delete p` will call the destructor of the class, and if that destructor is non-trivial it might need to access members of the class to free related resources, but those members have been overwritten by the `memset`.

The equivalent would be to invoke the destructor explicitly, call `memset`, then use `operator delete` to free the memory:

```
Foo* p = new Foo();
p->~Foo();
memset(p, 0, sizeof(Foo));
::operator delete(p);
```

**But** the compiler is allowed to optimise away the memset if it can see that noone accesses the memory again, so the CERT advice is not very good.

Comment: The last issue is also discussed here http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1381.pdf